# I keep getting module 'pandas' has no attribute 'DataFrame' and I can not remove and re-install pandas package

Tags: python, pandas, pip

I am using conda env, and I am trying to run a python script that converts xml file to pandas dataframe. But I keep getting this error:

```
xml_df = pd.DataFrame(xml_list, columns=column_name)
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'DataFrame'
```

So I thought I would uninstall and re-install back again the pandas library in my conda env. But I can't even delete the pandas package using conda remove or pip uninstall. I am getting this error:

```
 with open(path, 'rb') as stream:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\users\\bla\\anaconda3\\envs\\tensorflow\\lib\\site-packages\\pandas-1.2.4.dist-info\\RECORD'
```

Then I thought it might be issue with the new pandas==1.2.4 version and I tried to `pip install --upgrade pandas==1.2.3`  and now I am getting different error:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\users\\bla\\anaconda3\\envs\\tensorflow\\lib\\site-packages\\pandas-1.2.4.dist-info\\METADATA'
```

I went to check in my file directory and clearly I do not see those files. When I installed the pandas, I installed using `pip`. Now I am not sure what to do because I am stuck. I can not remove or even upgrade the pandas to solve that error. I really do not want to delete and re-start my env since I have a lot of packages installed. I would appreciate your help. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, quit all running Python sessions. Then, go into the `c:\users\bla\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages` folder and delete any files or folders that start with `pandas` or `~andas`, regardless of capitalization. Exit your virtualenv (don't delete it, just deactivate it), then enter/activate it again and run `pip install pandas`. This *should* fix the issues you're seeing.

Comment: I deleted all the pandas packages from the site-packages folder and when I tried to install pandas again, I run into this issue:
```ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\users\\bla\\anaconda3\\envs\\tensorflow\\lib\\site-packages\\pytz-2021.1.dist-info\\METADATA'```

So I tried to uninstall pytz using pip and it throw bunch of red errors. So, again I went to site-packages and deleted all the pytz folders. Then, I run ```npm install pandas``` and I installed pandas and pytz correctly and my program is running. Why would this happen?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Next time, I will just go to site-packages folder and delete all the red flagged packages and re-install them.

Comment: I have this issue when syncing my source code. After syncing, sometimes I have to uninstall my pandas from my virtual environment and rebuild pandas from source, and then install it. I am working on upstream version as in contributors documents says, and debugging this this version. Is it right to build sometimes to force error go or there exists another correct way?

Answer (score 0):

You might have another file called `pandas.py` in your directory or a variable called `pd` in your program. Check if you do, and rename the file/variable.

Comment: No I checked all the files and I did not have any file named close to pandas.